# EPPlus Number Format according to different Culture

Tags: c#, epplus, cultureinfo

[This the Excel Screenshot link to show example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GPHK.png) In a particular cell, It consists double value but showing rounded value in the cell.

like If in the cell the value is  553236  but the original value is 553236.456001

and can only see this value on top bar when click on that particular cell.

But my question is I have converted the original value into Italian currency, How to  make it do the same as above

- In Italian Culture 553,236.456 value will be converted as 553.236,456
- Have to show only 553.236 and when Click on Particular cell On top bar value should be 553,236.456

For converting the value into Italian culture I used the code as below

```
Convert.ToDouble(cellValue).ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("it-IT")).Split(' ')[0]
```

used split to not show currency symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many trials like

```
cell.Value = Convert.ToDouble(cellValue,new CultureInfo("it-IT").NumberFormat);
```

and

```
cell.Value = Convert.ToDouble(cellValue).ToString("N",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("it-IT")).Split(',')[0];
```

I understood that number format or number according to culture is dependent on your system's region. If numbers are getting converted to different culture and were not showing or showing wrong format, that is cause of local system's region. If u change ur region to that particular culture. You'll get the perfect answer. 
I just did as per my country format in code like using

```
cell.Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0";
```

it worked fine with this. After committing code to svn, when I tried the Export of Excel from main website it was  working beautifully according to system's region. If I change to Italian, Excel output numbers were in italian format and when I change to Indian , the numbers were in Indian number format.

So Don't worry about whatever culture u want, do write according to ur culture all work's fine.
Over this if u still want to get number according to particular culture use the above second code, but problem is u will get numbers stored as text. that u can't add or do any valuations.

Comment: Glad to see you were able to resolve your issue. As far as my answer goes, was it not useful? Were the custom formats I provided for testing not working? If it helped or indeed resolved your issue I'd appreciate an up-vote and accepted-answer. Thanks.

Comment: Fisrt of all Thanks for ur answer, u tried to help me atleast. It helped me, but that didn't solve my doubt/question. I gave upvote and bcoz of my reputation being less than 15 that didn't count

Answer (score -1):

You need to format the data cell.

Assign a number or custom format by setting the following property:

```
dataCell.Style.Numberformat.Format
```

Generate your custom format in Excel itself then just copy that format and set it to above property.

You can access cell formats in Excel by right clicking on a cell and selecting Format cell.

Comment: Custom format like #.##0.00 didn't work. Anyhow Thanks for ur Answer

Comment: Test this one out for example, I've used it for decimal type format: #,##0.00_);[Red]-#,##0.00  it means a number with two decimal places and paint red if value is negative, if it works and was useful please let me know so I can update my answer with that example and mark it as accepted answer and upvote, thanks