# How to separate decimals with comma using EPPlus to generate Excel

Tags: c#, excel, number-formatting, epplus

I want to use comma as decimal separator and point as thousand separator for excel generation, but it doesn't work in EPPlus. As an example I use the code block below for formatting. It generates decimals like "2,300.250" but I need to generate decimals like "2.300,250". Is there a workaround for this ?
Note that, another question answers [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61509186/epplus-number-format-according-to-different-culture) if you accept to get number as text.

```
else if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.In(typeof(double), typeof(decimal)))
{
       ws.Cell(row, cell).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "#.##0,00";
       ws.Cell(row, cell).Value = propertyInfo.GetValue(detail);                                             
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EPPlus Number Format according to different Culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61509186/epplus-number-format-according-to-different-culture)

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi it answers if only I accept to get numbers as text.